# Getting PLS-00324 error when compile a Package Body

Tags: database, oracle, package

when I compile this code below, I get PL-00324 error. This error says the variable V_CD_ESTADO couldn't recieve the return from the cursor C_VERIFICA because it's not a cursor. Weird, no? I research a lot, but a couldn't find something  that helps me... So, i'll be very grateful if anyone helps me!

PLS-00324 cursor attribute may not be applied to non-cursor 'string'

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PCK_TB_ESTADO
IS
  FUNCTION FNC_VALIDA_ESTADO
  (P_CD_ESTADO IN TB_FUNCIONARIO.CD_ESTADO%TYPE)
  RETURN BOOLEAN
  IS
    CURSOR C_VERIFICA
    IS
      SELECT CD_ESTADO
      FROM TB_FUNCIONARIO
      WHERE CD_ESTADO = P_CD_ESTADO;
    V_CD_ESTADO TB_FUNCIONARIO.CD_ESTADO%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    OPEN C_VERIFICA;
      FETCH C_VERIFICA INTO V_CD_ESTADO;
    IF V_CD_ESTADO%NOTFOUND THEN
      RETURN TRUE;
    ELSE
      RETURN FALSE;
    END IF;
    CLOSE C_VERIFICA;
  END;
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check if the cursor state of not found `C_VERIFICA%NOTFOUND` instead of the variable `V_CD_ESTADO`

Answer (score 1):

Cursor attributes `%FOUND`, `%NOTFOUND`, `%ROWS%`, `%IS_OPEN` etc. apply to `CURSOR`s only. I.e. cursors defined as `CURSOR cursor_1 IS ...`.

In this case the cursor `cursor_1` can have these cursor attributes. Such as `cursor_1%IS_OPEN`, `cursor_1%NOTFOUND` and so on. In your code, you are apparently associating a cursor attribute with a non-cursor element i.e. `V_CD_ESTADO`, which is just a variable of `TB_FUNCIONARIO.CD_ESTADO`'s `TYPE`.

What you intend to do is

```
IF C_VERIFICA%NOTFOUND THEN
RETURN TRUE;
ELSE
  RETURN FALSE;
END IF;
```

since `C_VERIFICA` is the cursor here.